# How do I read / get contents of a text message body?

Tags: php, sms, message, sms-gateway

I'm going to use a SMS to Web Server, which will forward incoming text messages to my web server.

The message body will contain some short codes, a mobile number and a amount in a format. I need to store the details separately to variables.

**Here's an example, what I will receive in my web server through POST method:**

```
$sender = "9999912345";
$date = "2017-04-14 13:04:40";
$message = "RCG ARTL 9700012345 50";
```

**I need to store the contents of $message separately to variables:**

```
$cmd = "RCG";
$op = "ARTL";
$no = "9700012345";
$amt = "50";
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $message = "RCG ARTL 9700012345 50";
    list($cmd, $op, $no, $amt) = explode(" ",$message);
```

you can test it.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is working as per my requirements!

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code:

```
$message = "RCG ARTL 9700012345 50";
$arr = explode(" ", $message);
$cmd = $arr[0];
$op = $arr[1];
$no = $arr[2];
$amt = $arr[3];
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is working as per my requirements!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function with space as the delimiter and then make sure exploded message (an array) is contains 4 key/value.

```
    $cmd = '';
    $op = '';
    $no = '';
    $amt = '';

    $explodedMessage = explode(' ', $message);
    if (count($explodedMessage)==4){
        $cmd.=$explodedMessage[0];
        $op.=$explodedMessage[1];
        $no.=$explodedMessage[2];
        $amt.=$explodedMessage[3];
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is working as per my requirements!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
$message = "RCG ARTL 9700012345 50";

list($cmd, $op, $no, $amount) = explode(' ', $message);

var_dump($cmd, $op, $no, $amount);
```

Output:

```
string(3) "RCG"
string(4) "ARTL"
string(10) "9700012345"
string(2) "50"
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is working as per my requirements!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the $message into an array using explode function where the delimitre will be a space. and then can access it the way you want it.

```
$message = "RCG ARTL 9700012345 50";
$messageArray = explode(" ", $message);
$someText = $messageArray[0];
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!